# How can I Animate LEDs?

Tags: animation, light

Hallo i want to animate the LEDs from the table, sure i could do it manual one by one, but how could i do it easier, like with one empty and everytime it hits the table the LEDs on this point goes on?[image]

Comment: Do you want to light up custom shapes or just circle around an empty?

Comment: please provide more context to your question. You want to send control information to a LED matrix? or you just want to render a virtual LED matrix for the purpose of superimposing it on recorded footage?  This is too vague

Comment: I want to animate the LED, when I put an object on the table that its react with it. Instead of an object I could take an empty just to track something. I think i have to do something with drivers but i never work with them so no idea.

Comment: Are you actually using LED's? or are you trying to have Blender emulate with video effects, that your hand is touching a white surface?

Comment: @3Dbob you could actually update a microcontroller with serial data via the serial library in python. Of course the microcontroller would then control the leds. This being said, I think something like simpleCV and python would be better suited with blender being left out of the mix (if you are trying to code with hand recognition in a video stream), blender would work but it may be more of a struggle.